# Difficulty in playing Music

Tags: sound, mp3

I'm a new Ubuntu user.  I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my desktop alongside windows 7.

When I try to play any mp3 file with Parole Media player (which I believe is the default) , it says :

> Parole needs MPEG-1 Layer 3(MP3) decoder to play this file. It can be
>   installed automatically.

Then I click Install and it gives error like `Required plug-in could not be found.`

Even when I am connected to the Internet .

I read many solutions on this very forum , but none of them seemed to work .

The last thing I tried was to manual download and install the MP3 plug-in package . It installed successfully, but I still can't play Music.

Comment: Just a note on the side: 13.10 is soon to be End-of-Life'd. Only use it if you have a specific reason to be on an older release.

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu, or Xubuntu? Rhythmbox is the default on Ubuntu, but Parole is the player on Xubuntu, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the Ubuntu Partner Archives and install the Fluendo MP3 plugin.

You may also want to install Ubuntu-Restricted-Extras, which includes LAME.  LAME generally provides better MP3 compression.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Parole in Ubuntu before. Although its from Xubuntu/XFCE but it works flawlessly on Ubuntu. To solve all the codec problems you need to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

For this you will have to enable universal repository (if you haven't already). If you don't have it enabled, go to "Software & updates" from dash or Settings. Then check all the checkboxes (except sources) and click Close. Then do one of the following:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for "`Ubuntu Restricted Extras`" and install it.
2. If you don't mind using the terminal here's what you should run:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

And you should have the problem solved.